# Is this CPU usage for TeamViewer on Ubuntu normal? If so, are there any better options?

Tags: wine, remote-desktop, cpu, teamviewer

[image]

This image was taken while logged in remotely via TeamViewer to my workstation.

- There are four TeamViewer_Desktop processes open (why?), two of them taking a large amount of CPU (why?).
- I tried connecting to a Windows system, and while the memory usage is about the same (a couple of hundred Mb) that only uses about 1 % CPU on the Windows system, indicating TeamViewer runs much better on Windows.

I am suspecting that TeamViewer for Linux is just a poorly implemented Wine bundle and that this might be expected, but I just wanted to confirm -- is this how you see TeamViewer performing as well? And if so, are there any better options that you can link guides to that accomplish the same firewall-agnostic remote desktop solution for both Windows and Linux?

Comment: As alternatives you could use [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/#download) or [Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Could you add more info about versions/editions you are using for both Ubuntu and TeamViewer, 64bit, which TV package used for installation...?

Comment: This is "9.0.24147 Dev wine-1.6", dated Nov 27 2013. I believe it's the newest version. I am running 14.04 (I know it's unsupported right now but I'm more interested in knowing if this is a common problem with TeamViewer or not). @OrangeTux: Thank you, but any options need the USP that TeamViewer has: it's routed through TeamViewer and will bypass firewalls, I think it's transferred over HTTPS. Can this be achieved with your options?

Comment: You can try Chrome Remote Desktop  - it works OK on Ubuntu 14.04 + Win 8.1 + Android 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Team Viewer is a popular universal remote control application. It runs on IOS, Linux, Android, Windows, and Mac etc. It is great that this software is available for Linux, but I have also observed high CPU load when it comes to active Team Viewer sessions. The CPU load goes away when you disconnect. Part of the explanation for this could be that the CPU is used for all rendering and not the graphics card, which may be why it has a lower CPU usage in Windows and Mac. Unfortunately I have been unable to find an alternative that is a perfect match.

All suggestions that suggest that somehow VNC or its derivatives are somehow a substitute, are ill researched suggestions. Though you can remote control a desktop session using VNC it is not nearly as efficient as TeamViewer. NX and its derivatives are on equal par when it comes to performance, and there are even open source implementations that use RDP quire successfully. However, no other solution allows you to traverse firewalls and NAT with absolutely no configuration. Team Viewer works in the same way as Skype does in the sense that it simply auto discovers how to get to the internet and sign in, then locates all the associates to your account (computers in the case of Team Viewer). This is the main feature of Team Viewer and the main reason it has become so popular; and I am sad to see that there is no open source counterpart to team Viewer. 
An open source implementation of Team Viewer would be a seriously useful tool in combination with Ubuntu One or something similar.

To mitigate the effects of high CPU use you can try to set a lower priority for the teamviewerd, and TeamViewer GUI processes. You may also be able to buy a license and then open a bug or case in regards to CPU load and see if they address the problem. Otherwise I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

May be too late to answer but I observed this on my setup Ubuntu 14.04 machine (6 cores) accesses from a Windows 10 machine using TeamViewer 11. The CPU usage would shoot up to 400% at times.

I disabled the animation effects on Ubuntu (using compiz settings manager) and the CPU load returned to "normal" (~50%).

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Please check to see if you are using your GPU - if ccompiz is processing the graphics, then you will see very high CPU utilization as the screen is drawn.  `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` then `glxinfo | grep -i "opengl render"` should provide information about what device is rendering the graphics.  If it is `llvmpipe` then the CPU is being used to render the graphics.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesGreen. I get "OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2" so the graphics is being rendered by GPU, it seems.